# How to judge whether two Rc point to the same object in Rust?

Tags: rust

I get in trouble when trying to write a linked list in rust.

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct LinkedList<T> {
    head: Link<T>,
    tail: Link<T>,
}
type Link<T> = Option<Rc<Node<T>>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
    elem : T,
    next : Link<T>
}
impl <T> LinkedList<T> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        LinkedList { 
            head : None, 
            tail : None
        }
    }
    fn push_front(&mut self, elem: T) {
        /* if head is None, take will return None */
        let mut a : Option<i32> = None;
        assert_eq!(a.take(), None);
        
        let node = Rc::new(Node {
            elem,
            next : self.head.take(),
        });

        if self.tail.is_none() {
            self.tail = Some(Rc::clone(&node));
        }

        self.head = Some(node);
    }
    fn pop_front(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        if self.head.is_none() {
            return None;
        }

        if self.tail.as_ref().unwrap() == self.head.as_ref().unwrap() {}
        todo!()
    }
}
fn main() {

    
}
```

above code is a simple linked list demo.

the important code is the following, and it's buggy apparently:

```rust
if self.tail.as_ref().unwrap() == self.head.as_ref().unwrap() {}
```

I don't know how to judge head and tail whether point to the same object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [`std::rc::Rc::ptr_eq()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.ptr_eq) for exactly this kind of situation.

> Returns true if the two Rcs point to the same allocation in a vein
> similar to ptr::eq.